# Z Notation: Representation of a 2D array

Tags: graph, multidimensional-array, formal-methods, z-notation

I'm a complete beginner at the Z notation. I need to represent a graph type in Z. The idea I have is to use an incidence matrix so that I can traverse freely between nodes and edges with ease.

The only problem is, I don't know how to specify the incidence matrix in Z. I would think that I need a 2D array, but looking through the reference material available for the Z notation, arrays are commonly represented using seq. Is there another way to specify a multi dimensional array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think a relation between nodes would be a better representation for an incidence matrix. Lets assume that we have a type node:

```
 [node]
```

Then a graph could be modelled as a relation between nodes:

```
graph : node \rel node
```

This would be a directed graph because there could be an edge n1->n2 in graph but not n2->n1. If you need an undirected graph you can add a further restriction:

```
graph\inv = graph
```

(The inverse of graph is the same as graph, i.e. if n1->n2 in graph, then n2->n1 must be in graph, too.)

If you really want to model an incidence matrix as a multidimensional array, you can define a function that maps from a position in the array to an integer, e.g.:

```
matrix: (node \cross node) \fun {0,1}
```

The relation between the two representations can be expressed as:

```
\forall n1,n2:node @ (n1,n2)\in graph \iff graph( (n1,n2) ) = 1
```

Comment: What is /rel in Z-notation

Comment: If some nodes have no incident edges, graph : node \rel node
how work?

Comment: "A \rel B" (LaTeX syntax) is "A <-> B" the set of all relations between A and B.

Comment: The solution above (implicitly) assumes  that the set `node` contains all edges of graph. If a node N has no incident edges, there wouldn't be a pair in graph where N is on the left or right side. But `[node]` declares the set as a constant, so you wouldn't be able to change the set of edges in the graph. One approach would be to define a constant `[NODE]` that contains all possible edges and define a subset `edges \subseteq NODE` with `graph: edges \rel edges`.